# microsoft teams is showing " f.a is not a constructor " in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have installed using

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/pool/main/t/teams/teams_1.3.00.16851_amd64.deb
```

When I visited files in any teams , it is showing "f.a is not a constructor"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installed using wget, I have solved this by installed from Microsoft Teams website.

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-teams/download-app#desktopAppDownloadregion

Then went to the directory and downloaded it and right-clicked on that file. Open the file with Software Installer.

When installed, it did not show the error.